# Proper type hint for functools.partial

Tags: python, mypy, functools

What's the proper type hint for `functools.partial`? I have a function that returns a `partial` and I want to type hint it so `mypy` doesn't throw any error:

```
def my_func() -> ?:
    return partial(foo, bar="baz")
```

More specific than `typing.Callable`

Comment: Would [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) suffice, or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: More specific to be honest...not sure if it's even possible

Answer (score 24):

You have a couple of options here, depending on exactly what you're going for.

I'm going to assume for example that foo is defined

```
def foo(qux: int, thud: float, bar: str) -> str:
    # Does whatever
    return "Hi"
```

If we use `reveal_type` we find that `partial(foo, bar="blah")` is identified as `functools.partial[builtins.str*]`. That roughly translates to a function-ish thing which takes anything and returns a string. So, you could annotate it with exactly that, and you'd at least get the return type in your annotation.

```
def my_func() -> partial[str]:
    ...

a: str = my_func()(2, 2.5) # Works fine
b: int = my_func()(2, 2.5) # correctly fails, we know we don't get an int
c: str = my_func()("Hello", [12,13]) # Incorrectly passes. We don't know to reject those inputs.
```

We can be more specific, which takes a bit of care when writing the function, and allows MyPy to better help us later. In general, there are two main options for annotating functions and function-like things. There's Callable and there's Protocol.

Callable is generally more consise and works when you're dealing with positional arguments. Protocol is a bit more verbose, and works with keyword arguments too.

So, you can annotate your function as

```
def my_func() -> Callable[[int, float], str]:
```

That is, it returns a function which takes an int (for qux) and a float (for thud) and returns a string. Now, note that MyPy doesn't know what the input type is going to be, so **it can't verify that** bit. `partial[str]` would be just as compatible with `Callable[[spam, ham, eggs], str]`. It does, however, pass without errors, and it will then helpfully warn you if you try to pass in the wrong parameters to your Callable. That is,

```
my_func()(7, 2.6) # This will pass
my_func()("Hello", [12,13]) # This will now correctly fail.
```

Now, let's suppose instead that `foo` were defined as follows.

```
def foo(qux: int, bar: str, thud: float) -> str:
    # Does whatever
    return "Hi"
```

Once we've got a `partial` passing `bar` as a keyword argument, there is no way to get `thud` in as a positional argument. That means there's no way to use Callable to annotate this one. Instead, we have to use a Protocol.

The syntax is a bit weird. It works as follows.

```
class PartFoo(Protocol):
    def __call__(fakeSelf, qux: int, *, thud: float) -> str:
        ...
```

Teasing apart that `__call__` line, we first have the `fakeSelf` entry. That's just notation: if call is a method, the first parameter gets swallowed.

Next, we have `qux`, annotated as an `int` as before. We then have the `*` marker to indicate that everything following is keyword only, because we can no longer reach `thud` in the real method positionally. Then we have `thud` with its annotation, and finally we have the `-> str` to give the return type.

Now if you define `def my_func() -> PartFoo:` you get the behaviour we want

```
my_func()(7, thud=1.5) # Works fine, qux is passed positionally, thud is a kwarg
my_func()(qux=7, thud=1.5) # Works fine, both qux and thud are kwargs
my_func()(7) # Correctly fails because thud is missing
my_func()(7, 1.5) # Correctly fails because thud can't be a positional arg.
```

The final situation that you could run into is where your original method has optional parameters. So, let's say

```
def foo(qux: int, bar: str, thud: float = 0.5) -> str:
    # Does whatever
    return "Hi"
```

Once again, we can't handle this precisely with `Callable` but `Protocol` is just fine. We simply ensure that the `PartFoo` protocol also specifies a default value for `thud`. Here I am using an ellipsis literal, as a gentle reminder that the actual value of that default may differ between implementations and the Protocol.

```
class PartFoo(Protocol):
    def __call__(fakeSelf, qux: int, *, thud: float=...) -> str:
        ...
```

Now our behavior is

```
my_func()(7, thud=1.5) # Works fine, qux is passed positionally, thud is a kwarg
my_func()(qux=7, thud=1.5) # Works fine, both qux and thud are kwargs
my_func()(7) # Works fine because thud is optional
my_func()(7, 1.5) # Correctly fails because thud can't be a positional arg.
```

To recap, the partial function returns a fairly vague functionish type, which you can use directly but would lose checking against the inputs. You can annotate it with something more specific, using `Callable` in simple cases and `Protocol` in more complicated ones.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! Question: the ellipsis you put in the `Protocol` definition is a _literal_ ellipsis? Or is it something that the user is supposed to fill by themselves? I suggest this is clarified in the body of the answer.